# Substracting 2 Decimal Numbers from Database issue

Tags: php, decimal

```
$total_cost and $amount_paid value is 2028.36 as shown in the bottom right screenshot 
// values are from database. both are type decimal 15,2

$balance = ($total_cost - $amount_paid);

the result is 2.2737367544323E-13
```

The result should be 0. I tried converting both to float. still doesn't work

check screenshot below. I tried printing the value, the result shown in the bottom right corner.

[image]

---

## Solved

**I did the calculation in the database level instead.**

```
$this->db->select('(SUM(ItemCost * OrderQty) - OrderAmountPaid) - Discount as Balance');
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have decimal numbers, it uses floating point, so you can have problems like this. Do the subtraction in the database.

Comment: https://ideone.com/4E8LVq i get 0

Comment: @AbraCadaver Hi bro, i have added the image. as you could see. the code is just simple substraction of total cost and amount paid. but the result was like that. i even debug as you could see in the right bottom image.

Comment: Do not use floating point numbers to represent currency because of problems exactly like this. Use a library that does it properly, like [MoneyPHP](https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money).

Comment: You should never use PHP's default floating-point numbers (float or double) for currency operations, because their results are approximate.  Instead, use PHP's BCMath module ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php ) to get exact numbers, or perform the calculation directly in MySQL on data with a type of DECIMAL.

Comment: @Max Thank you very much for the suggestion.

I've did the calculation in the database level instead and it works great